# How to convert from world space to canvas space in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a gun that shoots raycasts, and when the raycast hits an enemy, I want to spawn a damage popup that displays a number. I have a code that converts from world space to canvas space. In this case, world space is the position of the hitpoint of the raycast, and canvas space should be the position of the damage popup text.

Here is the code:

```
void positionSelf()
{
    Vector2 ViewportPosition = cam.WorldToViewportPoint(position);
    Vector2 ScreenPosition = new Vector2(
    ((ViewportPosition.x*canvasRectTransform.sizeDelta.x)-(canvasRectTransform.sizeDelta.x*0.5f)),
    ((ViewportPosition.y*canvasRectTransform.sizeDelta.y)-(canvasRectTransform.sizeDelta.y*0.5f)));
    myRectTransform.localPosition = new Vector2(ScreenPosition.x,ScreenPosition.y);
}
```

I call this method in the `OnGUI()` update, and it works fine. When I move my camera left or right, the damage popup stays aligned to the target that the raycast hit. However, if I move my camera up or down, the popup also moves up and down with it and is not aligned to the target. I tried using `position` and `anchoredPosition`, but it didn't work.

My canvas is set to screen space overlay, and it is set to scale with the screen size. The UI is rendered in another camera, which also renders the weapons. I tried setting the cam variable to both cameras, but the problem still occurred.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to solve this is to use world space on canvas mode, so you can spawn the popup on world space directly (you may need to use a canvas for each popup).

Comment: I have thought of that too, but many sources said that using multiple canvases is inefficient especially for such many objects as unity has to call ```repaint()``` for each one.

Comment: and its gives a weird effect if I try rotate it so its always facing the players so it seems like actual UI